# Is a recursive code overrunning the return value of a this function?

Tags: python, recursion

I am puzzled by this python code:

```
def Counting(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        print(x)
        x = x-1
        Counting(x)
    print("count up",x)
print(Counting(10))
```

#### #

```
The out put is:
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
count up 0
count up 1
count up 2
count up 3
count up 4
count up 5
count up 6
count up 7
count up 8
count up 9
None
```

What I don't understand is why the return value is None? Shouldn't I get the value of x? Is it possible to have a return value of my choice?

Thank you

Comment: `Counting(x)` -> `return Counting(x)`

Comment: My guess: it always returns when x=0, which it interprets as None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why the return value is None? Shouldn't I
>   get the value of x? Is it possible to have a return value of my
>   choice?

If a method doesn't have a explicit return python returns `None`. That's standard.

in line no 7 `Counting(x)` you are not capturing / returning what is returned. So when x is 0 and if x <= 0: returns 0 you ignore that.

you go to the `print("count up", x)` which prints 0.

now the method returns `None` which goes to the recursion caller. And finally comes back to the original method call as `None`. I hope it's clear now.

If you change your code as.

```
def Counting(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        print(x)
        x = x-1
        Counting(x)
    print("count up",x)
    return x

print(Counting(10)) # This will return 9

# here Counting(10) calls Counting(9) but ignores what it returns
# and Counting(9) calls Counting(8) but ignores what it returns
# Counting(10) finally returns x which is 9
```

On the other hand if you want to preserve the last value then that should be returned.

```
def Counting(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        print(x)
        x = x-1
        return Counting(x)
    print("count up", x) # this line is dead code.

Counting(10) # This will return 0

# here Counting(10) returns what Counting(9) returns. 
# and Counting(9) returns what Counting(8) returns and so on....
# finally returning Counting(0)
```

> Is it possible to have a return value of my choice?

Yes, Depending on what value you want to return from what state of the recursion you can get what you want. It's programming. Anything that you can logically explain can be done with programming :)

Comment: I had to think about it a bit. So, when I have another method that returns another thing, it just overwrite what I intended it to return. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good to know your confusion is gone :)

Comment: @KimW I have added better explanation. Recursion is one of my favourite topics in CS :)

Answer (score 0):

In the function, you are not returning anything.

Update the function as follows

**Code**

```
def Counting(x):
    result = None
    if x <= 0:
        return x
    else:
        print(x)
        x = x-1
        result = Counting(x)
    print("count up",x)
    return result


print Counting(10)
```

Comment: Well, returning x after print gives me 9 which is not the number I want. I want to get the final x which is 0 but considering how the recursive code goes the value of x just get lost somewhere hehe.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. After using your code it appears that the rest of the code just stop running so I don't get the "count up," part of the code

Comment: That completely changed the output but the return value is 0

Comment: Thank you so much! That's helpful.

Comment: @KimW You just accepted a wrong answer.Please check the answers :D : )